# Create new Plone package Error

Tags: python, plone-4.x, plone-3.x

When i am trying to create new package for my Plone site,i got following trace.
Command that i used:

```
paster create -t plone myorg.mypackage   


 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/paster", line 4, in <module>
    command.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 104, in run
    invoke(command, command_name, options, args[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 143, in invoke
    exit_code = runner.run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 238, in run
    result = self.command()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paste/script/create_distro.py", line 73, in command
    self.extend_templates(templates, tmpl_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paste/script/create_distro.py", line 267, in extend_templates
    'Template by name %r not found' % tmpl_name)
LookupError: Template by name 'plone' not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nifty ways to generate a Plone-addon-bloilerplate, four of them explained:

### 1.) [paster](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/paster)

The error-message tells you that there is no template name 'plone' available, it should be:

```
$ paster plone_basic myorg.mypackage
```

### 2.) [zopeskel](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ZopeSkel)

You probably mixed up zopeskel's corresponding template-name with paster's, in this case, they actually do the same, as zopeskel is a project deriving of paster and bases upon it. Here a template named 'plone' is available:

```
$ zopeskel plone myorg.mypackage
```

To see all available template-names of zopeskel, do:

```
$ zopeskel --list
```

### 3.) [mr.bob](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.bob)

I haven't used it, but it's propagated massively these days, so you might want to have a look, the command would be:

```
$ mrbob -O myorg.mypackage bobtemplates:plone_addon
```

### 4.) [adi.devgen](https://github.com/ida/adi.devgen/)

Disclaimer: I'm the author. The motivation was to not be depending on other libraries and thereby avoid conflicts, that is: It doesn't have any dependencies, just some Python-methods. The corresponding command is:

```
$ devgen addProfileSkel myorg.mypackage
```